# Encrypt/Decrypt Images/Video/Audio with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption

Today I'm coming with technical question stuck in my mind.

I'm working in a hobby app for me, to learn about encryption / decryption, [using this JavaScript library](https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico) I'm able to encrypt/decrypt different text strings, which actually is awesome.

But it's possible to do the same with a video? An image? An Audio file? What would be the result? Another file? A string? (I don't mean with the above JavaScript library, but with another?)

Would be possible to save that as "text"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working in a hobby app for me, to learn about encryption / decryption, using this JavaScript library I'm able to encrypt/decrypt different text strings, which actually is awesome.

I like your enthusiasm, but please bear in mind that Julias Caesar was already able to encrypt text strings. OK, not securely, but still.

That library seems to be an accident waiting to happen, the code is one big swath of undocumented, untested and hard to maintain code.

> But it's possible to do the same with a video? An image? An Audio file? What would be the result? Another file? A string? (I don't mean with the above JavaScript library, but with another?)

Modern ciphers, including block ciphers and RSA are defined to operate on bits or - more specifically - bytes. Binary data can be best encrypted from and to binary data. If you are encrypting text, then it is very likely that you first encode to binary, and then encrypt. Some libraries - especially for higher languages such as JavaScript - may hide this fact.

If you want to save binary as text then you can base 64 encode it. That's also what this library does for the ciphertext it seems. That it first converts to hex (base 16) and then to base 64 is rather dumb if you ask me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Maarten Bodewes. Do you recommend me any other/modern JavaScript library instead of the mentioned above? I would like to encrypt text, but also images, videos or audio files.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't have any particular recommendations for JS encryption. Most people here seem to use [tag:cryptojs].

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to answer me. This will help me a lot to learn and understand better practices and leave unsecure or bad ways to encrypt data. I would like to ask you one more question regarding cryptojs https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/ they have 4 ways to encrypt data [SHA-1, SHA2-, SHA-512 and SHA-3]. If you were going to use cryptojs and would like to encrypt plain text with important information like (notes, Credit cards, Passwords, email addresses) which one of those would you be using? One thousand of thanks!! Have a great day sir.

Comment: None. Those are secure hash algorithms, not encryption algorithms. Generally you'd use AES, preferably in an authenticated mode such as GCM. Or, in the case of passwords, you'd use a password hash and not encrypt them at all. You need to study cryptography before you can apply it.

Comment: So how https://bitwarden.com/ saves credit card info, passwords? I.E if I use hash algorithms to encrypt the data, and I store those "encrypted strings" in various pieces like 4-5 in different servers wouldn't be that secure? Thanks

Comment: I am not aware what protocols and container formats they use internally. I'm afraid that this is a bit out of your league for the moment. Try and follow a crypto course, such as Coursera Crypto I from Dan Boneh or the one from Maryland University.